# braintree not havingt to enter credit card data each time

Tags: braintree

Asuming that I have a customer registered who already provided his credit card data and I don't want him enter it again on a next purchase, how would I do that? Right now I am using hosted fields and each time when testing I have to enter credit card data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure the customer's information (including payment method information), is being stored in the Braintree Vault.

You can create a customer by itself, with a payment method, or with a credit card with a billing address. Example of a customer creation;

```
result = braintree.Customer.create({
  "first_name": "Charity",
  "last_name": "Smith",
  "payment_method_nonce": nonce_from_the_client
})


result.is_success
# True

result.customer.id
# e.g 160923

result.customer.payment_methods[0].token
# e.g f28w39
```

If you intend to create a transaction at the same time as a customer, you may want to use [Transaction.sale()](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/request/transaction/sale/) with either the [options.store_in_vault_on_success](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/request/transaction/sale/#options.store_in_vault_on_success) or [options.store_in_vault options](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/request/transaction/sale/python#options.store_in_vault).  For example:

```
result = braintree.Transaction.sale({
"amount": "10.00",
"payment_method_nonce": nonce_from_the_client,
"customer": {
  "id": "a_customer_id"
},
"options": {
"store_in_vault_on_success": True,
  }
})
```

Once their information is stored in the Vault, you can pass their payment method token in the transaction API call, rather than a nonce.

Comment: Hi again @ThinkAboutIt another question, I am wondering about subscription, I inspected the braintree source code and could not find anywhere that they do "store_in_vault_on_success": True, when it comes to subscriptions. Is this automatically on when doing subscriptions?

Comment: by the way I looked into documentation and noticed that they use 'storeInVaultOnSuccess' instead of "store_in_vault_on_success", which is correct?

Comment: https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/request/transaction/sale/php#options.store_in_vault_on_success

Comment: @Maxlight Subscriptions by design use ALREADY stored payment methods to fund those recurring charges.  Using "store_in_vault_on_success" or 'storeInVaultOnSuccess', which are both legitimate, depending on your SDK, are used following Transaction.sale() calls to store the information about the customer, including payment method, to a Vault record.

Comment: Thanks for the help